# gnuplot : How to use values in dat file as destination for arrows?

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following data in RecettesInvestissement2017.dat

```
Excédent de fonctionnement capitalisé FCTVA et TA Caution Emprunt Subvention aménagement RD124 (Amendeuix) Subvention travaux de voirie 2015 Subvention travaux de voirie 2016 Subvention travaux de voirie 2017 Emprunt salle des associations Autofinancement  
7.32 1.95 0.07 38.35 11.19 0.76 1.36 0.90 2.87 35.23
```

Note that words in strings are separated with unbreackable spaces and strings in line one are separed with normal spaces.

My plotting file is like this

```
clear
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set boxwidth 2 absolute
set style fill solid border
set xrange [-2,14]
set yrange [0,110]
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset key
i=0
do for [name in "`head -1 'RecettesInvestissement2017.dat'"]{
i=i+1
set label i name at 6,5+6*i
set arrow i from 5.8,5+6*i to 1,5+6*i}
plot for [C=1:10] 'RecettesInvestissement2017.dat' u C
```

at the moment the result is the following
[image]

I still have to adjust fonts but before I would like to make the arrows arrive at the center of the relevant part of the stacked bar. I need help for that. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to plot arrows to the center of each colored area. You can use a function to calculate the Y position, and plot with vectors:

```
cumul_Y=0. #cumulative height
f(x)=(cumul_Y=cumul_Y+x, cur_Y=cumul_Y-x/2., cur_Y)
#cur_Y is a Y position
plot for [C=1:10] 'RecettesInvestissement2017.dat' u C, \
for [C=1:10] 'RecettesInvestissement2017.dat' u (5.8):(5+6*C):(-4.8):(f(column(C))-5-6*C) w vectors lc rgb('black'), \
for [C=1:10] 'RecettesInvestissement2017.dat' u (7):(5+6*C):(word(names,C))  w labels left font 'Arial,10'
```

Then you can add another section in the plot command, to plot with labels.

[image]

Here is the full script, it works for me. You have to add at beginning of the first line in data file a character `#` and space.

```
set term png size 1024,768
set output 'plot.png'
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set boxwidth 2 absolute
set style fill solid border
set xrange [-2:14]
set yrange [0:110]
unset xtics
unset ytics
i=0
names="`head -1 'RecettesInvestissement2017.dat'`"
cumul_C=0.
f(x)=(cumul_C=cumul_C+x, cur_C=cumul_C-x/2., cur_C)
unset key
plot for [C=1:10] 'RecettesInvestissement2017.dat' u C, \
for [C=1:10] 'RecettesInvestissement2017.dat' u (5.8):(5+6*C):(-4.8):(f(column(C))-5-6*C) w vectors lc rgb('black'), \
for [C=1:10] 'RecettesInvestissement2017.dat' u (6):(5+6*C):(word(names,C+1)) w labels left font 'Arial,10'
unset output
reset
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think labels are different because the copy paste changed the unbreakable space into a normal space.

Comment: I am trying it. At the moment it doesn't work but I need  to investigate as I am not very used to gnuplot

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I get with your script
[image]

Comment: I tried gnuplot 4.6 an 5.0, it works fine in both versions.

Comment: Version 5.0 patchlevel 5    last modified 2016-10-02

Comment: Have you added # and space in beginning of the line with labels?

Comment: I didn't understand it was in the data file at first. It works now. Thanks again for your patience.